How to list all image files from github repo
My question is a variation of this How to get a count of all the files in a git repository? : I would like command to return a web page listing all image files in a repo, like .png, .jpg etc.  Better yet, have them show on the page, can it be done?

It’s simpler to list all files for a remote-tracking branch since that operates on your local repository (not the GitHub repository).

how does it address my question?

git checkout origin/main; git ls-files '*.png' '*.jpg'

can I write filenames in .html file and make them into hyperlinks?
